# Blackberry: accessing a remote json file within blackberry app

Tags: json, blackberry

this my json file host in remote server.

```
{"posts":[{"id":"1","message":"message1","details":"5"},{"id":"3","message":"message2","details":"21"}]}
```

I want to access this file within my blackberry file where id =1. how do i do that? please someone help me

Comment: please specify exactly what you want .This is incomplete question

Comment: I have host these JSON file in remote server,now i want to display these data in a list when i click a button (where id=1). this only a dummy data.how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can start from ["Code sample: Parsing a JSON data structure"](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21128/Code_sample_Parse_JSON_data_structure_1319797_11.jsp)
at some point in the JSONOutputScreen class maybe you want to add a method to access exactly your stuff